# What is the dome/bubble around certain enemies in Diablo III?

Tags: diablo-iii

Some enemies in Diablo III have a nearly-transparent, blueish dome/bubble around them; it's much larger than the [Shielding](https://www.diablowiki.net/Shielding) bubble (with a radius maybe two or three times the height of your character), and it can pass through walls.  The Keywardens have it, and I've also occasionally seen it on elite mobs.  What does this dome do?

Here's an image [from Diablo Wiki](https://www.diablowiki.net/File:Sokahr-the-keywarden1.jpg) of a Keywarden with its bubble:

[image: Sokahr the Keywarden with its bubble]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*[Sokahr the Keywarden](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Sokahr_the_Keywarden)* can use several monster traits: Vortex, Mortar, Electrified and Missile Dampening.

[Missile Dampening](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Monster_Traits_(Diablo_III)#Missile_Dampening), in particular, has this visual effect:

> This trait is **shown by a blue dome around the imbued monster**. Projectile attacks that enter this sphere have their speed decreased by 90%, making ranged attacks less effective.

[image: Missle Dampening]

Comment: Note that certain attacks may become more effective instead. For example, the Ball Lightning Rune on Demon Hunter's Elemental Arrow will yield many more damage tics than otherwise.